# Crear página de perfil para un usuario con PHP

Tags: php

He estado trabajando en una página y es la primera vez que necesito crear un perfil para un usuario una vez creado, es decir, como ingresar a tu perfil de usuario de facebook.

**REFORMULO TODO NUEVAMENTE:**

Yo tengo una pagina con todos los perfiles existentes de cada persona y quiero que un usuario acceda al perfil de cada uno

```
<h3>USUARIOS EXISTENTES</h3>
      <?php foreach ($usuarios as $users){ /*Selecciona todos los usuarios existentes */?>
      <a href="users.php?=<?php echo $users['nombreUser'];?>"> <?php echo $users['id_users'];?></a>
      <?php } ?>
```

Esto me redirecciona a la página users.php?=(Numero de id de usuario). Hasta ahi no tengo problema, el tema es obtener los datos de ese usuario al ingresar a esa pagina.
Yo cree la pagina de users.php y quiero solo leer por ejemplo su nombre. Como debo llamar a la id de éste usuario y poder visualizar todos sus datos?

Espero se entienda

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu problema. Si sabes como acceder al usuario y buscar los datos y mostrarlos, cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Ahi lo modifique espero que se entienda

Answer (score 1):

te daré una breve explicación con respecto al Hipervinculo "**Perfil**".

La forma en la que llames o invoques a la pagina de perfil del usuario varia en el caso que mencionas:

```
<a href="http://miweb.com/perfil.php?id=(Numero de id)">Perfil de adgfg</a>
```

Estas diciendo a la pagina "perfil.php" que recibirá por le método **GET** el **ID** del usuario en cuestión si deseas hacerlo así es valido aunque no recomendado, dado que si nos ponemos a analizar el usuario esta logueado o ha iniciado sesión por lo tanto conocemos el **ID** del mismo por lo que no es necesario pasarlo.

**Propuesta**

Lo primero que te sugiero es tener una pagina llamada **perfil.php** que es lo mas lógico, segundo debo suponer que al validar el usuario estas asignando a variables de **SESSION** el id del usuario, bien con estos datos puedes hacer algo así:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../database.php';
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario']; //el cual debes tener al validar el login
//realizo la consulta
$sql= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $idUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchObject();
?>
```

bien con esto ya tenemos los datos del usuario ahora resta armar el diseño o la manera como desees mostrar el perfil y tambien los datos que posees de este ejemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="actualizarPerfil.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Usuario:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="usuario" value="<?=$row->usuario;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Correo:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="correo" value="<?=$row->correo;?>"></td>
</tr>
...

</table>
<button type="submit">Grabar Datos</button>
</form>
```

Si te fijas estoy mostrando los datos ya consultados anteriormente todo esto debe estar dentro de la misma pagina "perfil.php".

Ahora si te fijas existe un **form** con su respectivo **action** invocando a "**actualizarPerfil.php**" este archivo sera donde reciba los datos enviados por el usuario para actualizarlos mediante el metodo POST.

Recuerda este es un ejemplo muy básico y los datos a mostrar en perfil.php varían a lo que desees mostrar y tengas en tu tabla.

Espero te sirva y suerte...

Comment: Yo no termino de entender la pregunta. Y sobre la respuesta, es muy similar al de la pregunta, y como si fuera poco esta sujeto a inyecciones sql, cosa que el codigo original no porque usa consultas preparadas.

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres, mi pregunta va mas relacionada a como puedo dirigirme tanto a mi perfil como al perfil de otro usuario desde el mio.

Comment: @Marcos saludos, para esto asumo que serás el admnistrador del sistema por lo cual debes o deberías tener otras opciones como "Administrar Usuarios" esta opción tendra el listado de usuarios y al hacer click tal como comentas mediante un hipervinculo puedes redirigirte al respectivo perfil de c/u de los usuarios incluido el tuyo.

Comment: Igual no entiendo tu pregunta, si lo que estamos viendo es simplemente hacer una consulta a una tabla de usuarios, buscando por el ID_USER (usando el metodo GET). y mostrar el resultado de la consulta en una pagina con formato. Cual es el problema?? como poner un recordset con la informacion obtenida?? Debes ser mas clara tu pregunta.

Comment: Claro, no es la primera vez que me pasa de no poder expresar correctamente mi consulta. Una vez direccionado a la pagina del usuario como obtengo su id segun el que seleccioné? es decir, como interactuo con el id en http://miweb.com/perfil.php?id=(Numero que quiero obtener en la pagina)

Comment: El ID lo obtienes desde la primera consulta que haces al perfil del otro usuario. Si después quieres conservar ese ID, lo puedes guardar en una variable de sesión. Sigue siendo un poco ilógica tu pregunta. A ver si con alguna ilustración o diagrama de flujo puedes representar lo que buscas.

Comment: Ahi lo modifiqué a ver si alguien lo entiende, solo quiero visualizar los datos de quien corresponda en el perfil al que uno elige acceder

Comment: Ok ya esta un poco mas claro... En tu pagina donde esta la lista de usuarios. cuando haces el SELECT * FROM usuarios. que te arroja todos tus usuarios y que es lo que recorres con el foreach. ahí es donde puedes listar ademas del nombre, el campo ID_USER de la tabla usuarios. es lo que vas a poner en el URL.. <a href="users.php?id_user=<?php echo $users['id_user'];?>">. Ya cuando llegue la ID_USER a tu pagina users.php, harás una consulta a la tabla usuarios pero filtrando por el ID_USER. algo así SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user= $_GET['id_user'] esto te regresara la información del user.

Comment: Gracias! Ha sido justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score -1):

Definitivamente tendras que auxiliarte de una variable de SESSION; una vez que el usuario haga login almacenas sus datos en esta variable. Ya luego puedes recuperar los datos que quieras mostrar en el perfil desde esa variable de SESSION ya existente previamente.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]